# Has a manga series ever affected Jump or similar magazines sales a lot?

Tags: manga-history

For example when Naruto started or ended has the sales ever fluctuate?

Comment: _Shounen Jump_ is almost entirely made of serialized manga. I think it's a safe bet that yes, sales vary based on which manga series are being serialized - what else would affect people's decision to buy or not buy a particular volume?

Comment: I think that as @senshin said, which mangas are in it affect the sales greatly (like you would run to the bookstore to learn what happens in the last chapter of naruto and all) but at the same time, it seems like Jump and other are like weekly magazine for us. You will always go buy it to see if there is any new interesting things in it. So you would already have a lot of people buying it each week as it's cheap and has lot of new things in it, but those people would want even more to buy them if a manga they love is published in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found you an article that show some graphs about Jump sales, and data about their best selling mangas that I think you'll find useful :

[source](https://comipress.com/article/2007/05/06/1923.html)

And some date from best selling mangas to help you evaluate those graphs :

Saint Seiya (1986 - 1990)

Dragon Quest: Dai no Daibouken (1989 - 1996)

Hokuto no Ken (1983 - 1988)

Slam Dunk (1990 - 1996)

YuYu Hakusho (1990 - 1994)

Comment: It's probably also worth mentioning that Dragonball ended in 1995.